# Editing .NET Resources with Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, resources

I am attempting to edit some resources in another .NET executable, using reflection.

Is this possible/how would I do this? Or am I going down completely the wrong route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be heading down the wrong route. The CLR does not allow you to edit the metadata tables of any assemblies loaded into the current AppDomain.  What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm actually trying to save a script into the resources of the exe, so it is basically a self-extracting file.

Answer (score 1):

> [Reflexil](http://sourceforge.net/projects/reflexil/) is an assembly editor and
>   runs as a plug-in for Reflector. Using
>   Mono.Cecil, Reflexil is able to
>   manipulate IL code and save the
>   modified assemblies to disk. Reflexil
>   also supports 'on the fly' C# and
>   VB.NET code injection.

Comment: Reflexil is not yet able to inject/delete/rename/edit resources. It will be available in the next version (1.3)